# Concrete Hanson-Wright inequality?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, quadratic-forms

I'm working on a paper that requires bounding

$$\Pr\left[|\vec x^\top Q \vec y| >= t\right]$$ where $Q$ is a matrix (happens to be symmetric) and $\vec x,\vec y$ are iid real mean-zero subgaussian random vectors.  As I understand it, the Hanson-Wright inequality bounds this as $$2\exp\left(-c \cdot\min\left(\frac{t^2}{k^4 ||Q||_F^2}, \frac{t}{k^2||Q||_2}\right)\right)$$ where $k$ is the subgaussian parameter and $c$ is an absolute constant.

But I'm trying to derive an actual numerical bound.  Is there a paper which gives an actual value of $c$, preferably a tight one?  Possibly it would be different for the two sides of the min().  Thanks.

Comment: For $Q$ sparse, lemma 3.1 in [1] shows $c=\frac{1}{4e}$ works for the diagonal terms. The off diagonal terms are a bit messy but there are some constants appearing later in the same paper. [1]: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~shuhengz/research/sparseHW.pdf

Comment: @JosiahPark the link above doesn't work anymore. Here is one that does: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05517.pdf If in the future this one doesn't work, for reference the title is "Sparse Hanson-Wright inequalities for subgaussian quadratic forms" by Shuheng Zhou.